# Dynamically sized array

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

I've been trying to make a selling program where the customer will be asked the quantity of items he will buy. For example, if he inputs `"5"`, the next window will ask him 5 questions. My problem is, I'm required to use array, so is there any way that I can change

```
string[] arrmerch = new string[6];
```

the number is "6" in the new string with the what the user inputted? Here's the loop. The item choice is the question.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= arrmerch.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Item choice: ");
    arrmerch[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Replace the `6` with a variable containing the number you asked the user for...?  Check out `int.TryParse` if you still need to convert that input to a number.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use an array? You could accomplish the same thing quicker if you use a list.

Comment: @abhi because array is a requirement for this project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, just do this:

```
int userInput = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
string[] arrmerch = new string[userInput];
```

You will need to add input checking to ensure that what you have is an integer and not something else.

Here's an example with input checking:

```
int arraySize = 0;
if(Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arraySize))
{
    string[] arrmerch = new string[arraySize];

    //the rest of your code
    //...
    //.
}
else
{
    //The user entered a value which cannot be parsed to an int
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change
    string[] arrmerch = new string[6];

to

```
string[] arrmerch = new string[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];
```

which will take the users input and create and array of that size.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int numberOfQuestions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Readline());
string[] arrmerch = new string[numberOfQuestions];

for (int i = 0; i <= arrmerch.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Item choice: ");
                        arrmerch[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

Will need error checking though.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use `Generic Lists`.They are more flexible, if you want to change your array lenght in the future

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
var list = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
{
     Console.Write("Item choice: ");
     list.Add(Console.ReadLine());
}
```